# How to Edit HKCU values with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

When I run the command to edit a registry value on HKCU with PowerShell, I have to run PS as an admin to have perms to edit the registry. Unfortunately, this changes HKCU to my admin account (as far as I can tell, at least), which keeps me from editing the user.

I need to automate this as we’re rolling out hundreds of machines. Am I missing something?

Comment: HKCU literally means "current user" (i.e., the user running the code). The problem is that you want to affect the registry as a particular user, and by far the easiest way to do that is to make the change _as that user_. Probably the most straightforward way to do this in an organized fashion is to use Group Policy setting rather than a script. If you really must do it via script, you would do it as a logon script.

Comment: I very much would prefer group policy but the geniuses higher up don’t think the people creating the computer images need group policy access.

Comment: This would not be an imaging issue but rather a configuration issue.

Comment: We’ve been tasked with doing both without group policy access.

Comment: You could use a logon script to make the change as the user logs on. Other than that, I would say that part of being in IT is being able to explain when a request is not realistic and/or provide alternative(s) that meet the requirements.

Comment: I absolutely agree. However, I am on my first week here and bottom end of the food chain on this project. I have explained and pitched this, and beyond that it’s out of my hands. Don’t mistake my asking here for an alternate solution as me not being dedicated to the better one.

Comment: In that case, there is not a way to accomplish what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

When running an elevated PowerShell, the user specific registry can be edited under `HKEY_USERS\<Users SID>\...`.  For example:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "registry::hkey_users\$($strSID.Value)\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop"
```

Comment: So my problem with this is it’s hundreds of users. This won’t save my any time ):

Comment: What are you really trying to do.  This answers your question but the real question is what and why.  If you have hundreds of users with roaming profiles you can edit those on the network share.  Or if these users are already using machines you can use the technique above to apply the settings remotely via `Invoke-Command`.  Please tell me more about the overall objective?

Comment: If this is an imaging issue and you have new users moving across you could set the desired values in the default user.

Comment: I’m setting up 1000-ish laptops. I can’t set this in group policy, so my goal is to change it in a script that we can have as part of the image. So for us to do what you recommend, we’d need to manually find the SID of a thousand users as we set up their machines and then put it in this command. No bueno.

Comment: if you are deploying new hardware with new user profiles then the best case is to edit the default profile on the machine.  During the build do something like this: `reg load "hku\temp" "%USERPROFILE%\..\Default User\NTUSER.DAT"` then you can set your properties like this `reg ADD "hku\temp\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop" /v SCRNSAVE.EXE /d "%windir%\system32\scrnsave.scr" /f` (for example) then unload `reg unload "hku\temp" `.  When the users login they get a new profile with that setting.

Comment: They’ll be logging in with an active directory profile that’s already been created on our domain, so unfortunately I don’t think this works. 

I’m surprised there’s not a way to just reference the currently logged in user on the machine- as in the profile that’s active, not the current account accessing Powershell.

Comment: ok, so run `$user = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty username` to get the current logged in user, then run this `$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user)` which will give you their user object, which can you can translate into their SID like this: `$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])` taking us back to the original answer ;-)

Comment: As I noted in comments on the question: It is much easier, simpler, and far less error prone to make the change as the logged on user.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I totally agree, but the original question was raised because the key in question couldn't be edited with current (aka normal) user credentials.